# Download in background in iPhone

Tags: iphone, download, ios4

Is it possible to download a file while the app is in background in iPhone 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under iOS 4.x, you can use request some background time using UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: and perhaps continue a file download for a limited period of time.

See Apple's [document](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) on "multitasking" background execution for details.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is.

It's supported in ASIHTTPRequest as of v1.8:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#background_downloads_ios

(There was also an experimental branch of v1.7 with it at http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/commits/backgroundtask but this appears not to exist anymore.)

It's also supported in AFNetworking, see [Does AFNetworking have backgrounding support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800614/does-afnetworking-have-backgrounding-support)

Comment: That URL gives "That page doesn't exist!", hopefully temporarily?

Comment: @JOM That functionality is part of the mainline as of v1.8 - I've updated my answer with a link to the documentation.

Comment: Is there a better solution nowadays ? something with AFNetworking perhaps? ASIHTTPRequest is no longer available.

Comment: @ShaiMishali I've added an AFNetworking link to my answer. ASIHTTPRequest is still available and works just fine, though may not be a good choice for new projects.