# Does AFNetworking have backgrounding support?

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, afnetworking

I'm in the process of investigating `AFNetworking` as a replacement for `ASIHTTPRequest`, and notice a complete lack of information on whether it supports background downloads/uploads.

With an `ASIHTTPReqeust` object, all you have to do is call `[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES]` and the request will continue in the background. Is there any support for this in `AFNetworking`?

Comment: If there isn't (I'm not sure whether there *is* support for background execution in `AFNetworking`), you could always port across whatever extra features you want from `AFNetworking` into `ASIHTTPRequest`, or add background execution support (relatively simple) to `AFNetworking`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**EDIT**: As of [AFNetworking 1.0RC1](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ), this is an *explicit* feature. `AFURLConnectionOperation` now has the method `setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`, which transparently manages all of this for you.

---

*It's an implicit feature, so I didn't really think about advertising it. All you'd need to do is:*

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskIdentifier = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) {
        [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskIdentifier];
        [[YourRestClient sharedClient] cancelAllHTTPOperations];
    }];
}
```

*Or, if you manage your operations in your own `NSOperationQueue`, just `-cancelAllOperations` here instead.*

Comment: Mattt - sounds like you're giving a solution for canceling networking when moving into the background though the question was about spawning/continuing AFNetworking ops when moving into the background. Thoughts on that? Given that most AF methods are block based / return immediately, I've found that the system believes they are complete before they really run their course... Maybe just using waitUntilFinished when running in a background mode?

Comment: @Hunter I think, you understand it wrong. Calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler ensures that requests continue in the background. The requests will not be canceled until the app is inactive for a longer time (like 10 min).

Comment: Yeah, you're completely right. I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote the above.

Comment: WARNING: do not use mattt's beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler code on applicationWillResignActive WITHOUT ADDING a matching call to endBackgroundTask - otherwise IOS will kill your app after 600 seconds, and foregrounding will relaunch your app.

Comment: `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
     UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundIdentifier = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) { [[AFHTTPClient sharedClient] cancelAllHTTPOperations]; }];
     [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundIdentifier];
}`

Comment: @mattt, I'm only now looking into AFNetworking, but it seems from your example that you can only do backgrounding on a global level, in contrast to ASIHTTPRequest's ability to specify which requests to background. Is this correct?

Comment: @BourbonJockey This will [likely be added to the next release](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/259) (1.0)

Comment: @mattt you might want to update your answer to mention the `setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` you've added.  I didn't realize it was there in the version I downloaded a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: You should add `__block` modifier to `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskIdentifier`, or the block will capture its initialized value.

Comment: @mattt I simply love AFNetworking but in a "legacy" project I'm using a `NSOperationQueue` object. I have a question for you and if you can reply I would be grateful. Within the `main` method of a `NSOperation` subclass, I download a from a service through `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error`. Once dowloaded, the file is imported within core data. A cancel request can happen at any time. So, does the cancellation could be handled in the right way or do I need to use aync pattern to deal with cancellation request? Thanks for your support.

Comment: What is the `[[YourRestClient sharedClient] cancelAllHTTPOperations];` line referring to?

Comment: cancelAllHTTPOperations seems not to be included any longer in the AFHTTPClient class. Instead use [[[YourHTTPClient sharedClient] operationQueue] cancelAllOperations];