# AFNetworking Background Task

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I'm currently working on replacing [ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) code with [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/). I have a scenario where I have multiple files to synchronize with the server. I want this task to continue in the background and I have noticed that the download is progressing when I'm in the background. I'm just curious and confused if I need to do any additional calls to support background downloading.

I found the following on a thread.

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskIdentifier = [application   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) {
    [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskIdentifier];
    [[NordecaAFAPIClient sharedClientWithBaseURL:[ECUserDefaults getNordecaApiURL]].operationQueue cancelAllOperations] ;
}];
```

What do I really require to write in order to support background dowloading?

The other question I have is that what is meant by the shouldResume flag found in the `AFDownloadRequestOperation`?

Comment: this question is a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800614/does-afnetworking-have-backgrounding-support

Answer (score 4):

As in [Does AFNetworking have backgrounding support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800614/does-afnetworking-have-backgrounding-support) , AFURLConnectionOperation now already supports `setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`, which basically does the background download management for you, as its performance is just the same as the normal UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier code in `applicationDidEnterBackground`, like what you wrote in the question.

And with regards to the `shouldResume` in `AFDownloadRequestOperation`, it's
   a symbol indicating that when the file is
   temporarily downloaded into a "incomplete" folder, which is a temp
   path, so when computing the already downloaded data size so that to
   know from where to resume the download, it will return a correct
   range.