# AFNetworking continue upload after going to background

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I use `AFAmazonS3` (which is an extention of `AFNetworking`)

It has `AFHTTPRequestOperation` that is created and added to the operation queue
`[self.operationQueue addOperation:requestOperation];`

The thing is that when the app goes to background it stops uploading and doesn't resume when it goes back.

How can I acheive it?
I saw some solutions but it was for the old version of `AFNetworking`

Comment: Two options: 1. If you just need a few minutes to finish a request even though the user has left the app, point 3 in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350125/afnetworking-2-0-and-background-transfers/21359684 shows an approach that is compatible with `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. 2. If you want proper background sessions (`NSURLSession` based), you have to abandon `AFHTTPRequestOperation` in favor of `AFHTTPSessionManager`. I walk through some of the issues on using `AFHTTPSessionManager` for background requests in that same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking supports Background operations.This post is mentioning `setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` and explaining how to use it https://stackoverflow.com/a/7881866/3033056 . 
This method is in `AFURLConnectionOperation` and `AFHTTPRequestOperation` inherits from `AFURLConnectionOperation`