# Continue download in background

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate, background-task

I am creating an application wherein I am downloading some data from server. While going in background I want that connection should continue running so that data can be downloaded. I know there is method in **appDelegate**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

which is called when application enters background. But as the connection is created in viewController, how can it be managed in **appDelegate**?
Also is/are there other way(s) this can be done?  I have gone through [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612963/download-in-background-in-iphone) link but is there a something simple to implement?

Comment: that is the official way to do it, thre are no other ways as much as i know

Comment: you should check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579810/ios-application-background-downloading

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way to do some operations that continue in the background is to create a separate thread to do the downloading.  Inside the thread, bracket your download operations between calls to beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: and endBackgroundTask.  You don't need to check to see whether you are running in the background or not, you just always call these two methods.

```
// Tell iOS this as a background task in case we get backgrounded
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
          beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];

//----------------------------------------------
// Perform your download operations here
//----------------------------------------------
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Tell iOS that we are done with stuff that needed to keep going even if backgrounded    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:taskId];
```

Comment: You can set ASIHttpRequest property :  [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Please correct me if I'm wrong: To conclude, there's almost no difference between running the task in background or foreground. Both would execute with this code. Yet 2 differences come to mind: 1. **if** your background task is too long, then maybe you would get terminated before finishing it! 2. It's better to `endBackgroundTask:taskId` so you'd save extra battery.

Answer (score 3):

[edit]
Sorry I was incorrect, as was pointed out in the comments you can extend the time limit you have to perform operations once/before your app goes into the background. Here is [Apple's Official Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)

Comment: This is not true, you can execute a [Finite-Length task](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW28) in the background for a maximum of 10 min.

Comment: @rckoenes you are indeed correct, my apologies. I will edit my answer. Thanks for the information :)

Comment: Still not true, you can call [`beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:) before executing the  Finite-Length task. You do not need to perform the operations once you go in the background. You can start the task before your app get pushed to background.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you handle your data downloading exactly. But you can take a look at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). It is very simple and straightforward, and works with ARC if you set the compiler flags to **-fno-objc-arc**. With this you only have to use

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES]; //For iOS 4.0 and up
```

And that works.

[Here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) you can see how ASIHTTPRequest works

Hope it helps!

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is not actively developed anymore... as per message [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). Just saying.

Comment: True, but it still works like a charm. I haven't found any good alternatives with as much functionality as ASIHTTPRequest.