# How to download a file even when the app goes into the background?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, background-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download in background in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612963/download-in-background-in-iphone)

I'm downloading a file in my app, using `connection:didReceiveData:` in `NSURLConnectionDelegate`. If I press the home button then the download is stopped. The delegate is not getting called to receive data.

When the app goes to the background, the app must continue downloading the file. How can I implement this?

There is a method `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` to start a finite-length task in background, is that what I need?

Answer (score 3):

This will allow you to download in background:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;

    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{ 
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask]; 
        }];

}
```